# Need help restoring Mac OS Notes

Tags: macos, notes.app

My work computer's RAM is broken. This isn't allowing it to boot properly. So I've got my personal mac tethered to the work mac via data transfer. I can see the notes DB files, and have transferred them to my personal computer, but I'm not sure how to access what is in there without wiping out what notes I have on my personal computer.

This has been asked in a few questions which are at least a year old, but I'm unable to comment on them, so forgive me for the re-ask. here's the one I was referencing to try to solve the issue: [Can't restore my Notes Mac OsX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328059/cant-restore-my-notes-mac-osx)

I also see this [Importing Notes from one mac to another?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274636/importing-notes-from-one-mac-to-another) but i'm afraid of doing it on my personal computer as I have notes currently there.

From another mac, I have transferred the notes files from the Containers folder (notesv7.storedata, notesv7.storedata-shm, notesv7.storedata-wal) as well as the notestore.sqlite file to the exact same version macos on my mac and want to look at the contents of these files / notes from a different system.

I tried to down load the mac-apt program [from where / what version] but my macOS [what version] won't run it [what precisely does won’t run look like].

- I changed to run from that developer but it just doesn't launch. (Needs to be deleted or clarified)
- I've tried both versions they have available for mac as well.  (Needs to be deleted or clarified)

As I understand it, the notes application stores notes as a DB so I need some way to get into that DB and export the info as a .csv or similar. I don't mind retyping/copying and pasting the data, but I do need to get to the data.

These files are from my work computer, where we couldn't use iCloud, and the RAM has gone bad and the whole logic board has to be replaced...which means if I can't figure this out I loose all of the information in my notes.

I have no backups of the work mac so I’m hoping I can figure out how to restore them to another computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you can link to the related questions in the body we can refine why the existing answers don’t help and perhaps get you an answer more quickly. A+ on asking a new question rather than commenting.

Comment: Can you use the Notes app now??

Comment: I've transferred the files to my personal mac, but I can't open them. I've tried the .html trick but that just gives me nonsense.

Comment: I also see that I can't just import the files to my note app on my personal computer. none of those files are active for me so I can't choose them to try.

Comment: OK - we’ve got enough to know we can’t help without some clarity. Is there a reason why you can’t just copy the user folder and had to select just those files? Migration Assistant would bring all your user files to the new mac without needing advanced help. Maybe some details and this can be reopened.

Comment: The work mac is out of commission. I have it tethered to my personal one via thunderbolt in data transfer mode. The RAM issue isn't allowing it to boot properly. So all I have are the raw notes files as I mentioned above. I'm worried that the migration assistant could overwrite the notes I have on my personal mac. would it? I've never used it before.

I suppose I could copy the user folder, but again, I don't want to overwrite what I have on my personal computer. The work one has to be sent off for a week to get fixed, but I need the notes because they have my passwords :(

Comment: also apparently my library folder isn't in my user folder. not sure why. i didn't move it. so i'm not sure if copying my user folder over would work because it might not contain the files i'm looking for.

Comment: Migration assistant can bring old user to a new user account. Why not pause and get a good backup of your current mac just in case?